# How to set Auth in laravel and when Two module

Tags: laravel-5

I install la-ravel but in only one module admin but i want to different module like as admin,super admin

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://medium.com/justlaravel/how-to-use-middleware-for-content-restriction-based-on-user-role-in-laravel-2d0d8f8e94c6

```
public function up()
{
Schema::create(‘users’, function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments(‘id’);
$table->string(‘name’);
$table->string(‘email’)->unique();
$table->string(‘password’);
$table->strint('adminrole');
$table->string(‘type’);
$table->rememberToken();
$table->timestamps();
 });
}
```